# Why is the second request failing? Can I change the order of RestSharp headers?

Tags: .net, vb.net, http, soap, restsharp

I'm trying to interface with my home mode/route/gateway that has a web UI that uses the CWMP (TR-69) SOAP protocol (via a javascript client) to manage the configuration.

I am trying to replicate (doesn't need to be extactly equal, but just to work) the first request done by the js client using RestSharp, but it always fails with a 500 internal error.

This is the RAW request from the javascript:

```
POST http://vodafone.station/data_model.cgi HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Method: POST
SOAPAction: cwmp:LoggedUser
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://vodafone.station/main.cgi?page=about.html
Accept-Language: it-IT
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Length: 230
Host: vodafone.station
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: wbm_cookie_session_id=5D2D2E84416DB43D

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><DMCookie>70972421</DMCookie></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><cwmp:LoggedUser xmlns=""></cwmp:LoggedUser></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the RAW request posted by my application using RestSharp:

```
POST http://vodafone.station/data_model.cgi HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
SOAPAction: cwmp: LoggedUser
Pragma: no-cache
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://vodafone.station/main.cgi?page=index.html
Accept-Language: it-IT
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/xml
Host: vodafone.station
Cookie: wbm_cookie_session_id=29374DCA6F4B4B8B
Content-Length: 230
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><DMCookie>657122696</DMCookie></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><cwmp:LoggedUser xmlns="></cwmp:LoggedUser></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I believe the two requests are basically the same, yet the second one fails.
The only difference here seems to be the header order, the user agent and the missing method header.

How can I change the order of the headers in RestSharp?

**Update**

I tried sniffing the original request from another browser to use it as base:

```
POST http://vodafone.station/data_model.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: vodafone.station
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 232
Origin: http://vodafone.station
Method: POST
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.0.418.3
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
SOAPServer: 
SOAPAction: cwmp:LoggedUser
DNT: 1
Referer: http://vodafone.station/main.cgi?page=about.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: wbm_cookie_session_id=1FD0F3015AA2D293

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><DMCookie>1795351746</DMCookie></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><cwmp:LoggedUser xmlns=""></cwmp:LoggedUser></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

This time I used the System.Net.HttpWebRequest class to recreate the request: it works, although my final objective is doing it with RestSharp.

So, this works:

```
POST http://vodafone.station/data_model.cgi HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://vodafone.station
Method: POST
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.0.418.3
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
SOAPServer: 
SOAPAction: cwmp:LoggedUser
DNT: 1
Referer: http://vodafone.station/main.cgi?page=about.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: wbm_cookie_session_id=04B71CB985477F19
Host: vodafone.station
Content-Length: 228

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><DMCookie>155497</DMCookie></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><cwmp:LoggedUser xmlns=""></cwmp:LoggedUser></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Update 2**

I did try to issue the above request using RestSharp:

So, here's the code:

```
Function GetLoggedUser() As RestSharp.RestResponse

        Dim T As New TokenAndCookieGetter

        Dim xaction As String = "LoggedUser"
        Dim xbody As String = Envelope(T.DM_COOKIE, xaction)

        Dim req = New RestSharp.RestRequest("/data_model.cgi", RestSharp.Method.POST)

        req.AddHeader("Origin", "http://vodafone.station")
        req.AddHeader("Method", "POST")
        req.AddHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01")
        req.AddHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
        req.AddHeader("SOAPServer", "")
        req.AddHeader("SOAPAction", "cwmp:" + xaction)
        req.AddHeader("DNT", "1")
        req.AddHeader("Referer", "http://vodafone.station/main.cgi?page=about.html")
        req.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
        req.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4")
        'Cookie is already set in T.CLIENT, by assigning a CookieContainer.
        req.AddHeader("Host", "vodafone.station")

        req.AddParameter("text/xml; charset=""UTF-8""", xbody, RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody)

        Return T.CLIENT.Execute(req)

    End Function
```

And here is the corresponding request, which miserably fails:

```
POST http://vodafone.station/data_model.cgi HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://vodafone.station
Method: POST
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
SOAPServer: 
SOAPAction: cwmp:LoggedUser
DNT: 1
Referer: http://vodafone.station/main.cgi?page=about.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.0.418.3
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Host: vodafone.station
Cookie: wbm_cookie_session_id=3FD15C2D16783BDD
Content-Length: 231

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><DMCookie>1534303835</DMCookie></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><cwmp:LoggedUser xmlns="></cwmp:LoggedUser></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: @Eser Is something wrong with that header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 3** *I solved the issue.*

So I finally found the problem. It wasn't any header.

It was case of bad character escaping. Shame on me.

```
Dim envelope As String = String.Format("<cwmp:{0} xmlns="">{1}</cwmp:{0}>", action, body)
```

I didn't escape the double quotes so the request would always cause a 500 error because of bad XML (the `xmlns="` attribute).

This is the final, working request:

```
POST http://vodafone.station/data_model.cgi HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://vodafone.station
Method: POST
Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
SOAPServer: 
SOAPAction: cwmp:LoggedUser
DNT: 1
Referer: http://vodafone.station/main.cgi?page=about.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.0.418.3
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Host: vodafone.station
Cookie: wbm_cookie_session_id=44D94CDF0F3ECD3C
Content-Length: 232

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><DMCookie>1554023074</DMCookie></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><cwmp:LoggedUser xmlns=""></cwmp:LoggedUser></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```